Django | Missing Positional Arguments
So Django is currently under the impression that I am missing positional arguments when I'm putting together a help section for a website. This includes help articles which are sourced from the Django model.
Everything works as expected until I include the unique help article reference number into my views.py file.
The error message is as follows:
help_center_article_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'support_article_reference'
MRE:
#utils.py
import requests, random, string
def generate_unique_number(charlimit):

    random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=charlimit))  # Generates a random string
    return f"{random_string}"

#models.py
from .import utils
class SupportArticles(models.Model):
    class TargetGroup(models.TextChoices):
        FOR_DEVELOPERS = 'developers','Developers'
        FOR_Clients = 'clients','Clients'
        FOR_FX_Providers = 'fx-providers','FX Providers'

    support_article_reference       =   models.CharField(max_length=50, default=utils.generate_unique_number(15), editable=False)
    support_article_title           =   models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Support Article Title")
    support_article_body            =   models.TextField(max_length=5000,verbose_name="Support Article Body")
    support_article_tags            =   models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Separate each tag category with a comma (,)", verbose_name="Support Topic Tags")
    support_article_group           =   models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=TargetGroup.choices,default=TargetGroup.FOR_Clients)

#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
def help_center_article_index(request, group, support_article_reference):
   
   support_article_object     = SupportArticles.objects.filter(support_article_group = group, support_article_reference = support_article_reference)
   if support_article_object.exists():
      meta_property_title     = support_article_object.first().support_article_group)
   else:
      meta_property_title     = "No articles available for this group"

   context = {
      
      'meta_property_title'       : meta_property_title,
      'meta_property_description' : meta_property_description,
      'support_article_object'    : support_article_object,
      'group'                     : group,

  }
   
   return render (request, 'help_center_article_index.html', context

#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hc',views.help_center, name="help-center"),
    path('hc/<str:group>/<str:support_article_reference>',views.help_center_article_index, name="help-center-article"),
]

#help_center_article_index.html
<div class="support-article-index__container">
        {% for support_article in support_article_object %}
        <a href="/hc/{{group}}/{{support_article_object.support_article_reference}}" class="support-article-index__inserted">
            <h3>{{ support_article.support_article_title | title}}</h3>
            <p>{{support_article.support_article_body}}</p>
        </a>
        {% empty %}
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">{{meta_property_title}}</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

I fail to see why Django returns this error when all positional arguments are present and correct. How would I essentially tell Django that this error message should not rear its ugly head?
Tried reading a few articles, but all here no good.
I was expecting to click on the URL link, which will take me to the relevant article with the URL being:
hc/<group>/<support_article_reference>

i.e.

hc/developers/123456789123

Full Traceback Message:
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/support/hc/developers

Django Version: 5.0.6
Python Version: 3.12.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'legal',
 'careers',
 'media',
 'blog',
 'events',
 'servicestatus',
 'django_bootstrap_icons',
 'announcements',
 'support']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - xxx\xxx\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - xxx\xxx\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: TypeError at /support/hc/developers
Exception Value: help_center_article_index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'support_article_reference'


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

@willeM_VanOnsem See Traceback message added, in code.

Your path('hc/<str:group>',views.help_center_article_index, name="help-center-article"), has no support_article_reference` parameter...

Does now! The result is still the same. Django can;t seem to see that there are no missing arguements

i think that in your href it should be {{support_article.support_article_reference}} instead of {{support_article_object.support_article_reference}}. i should add that support_article_object is  a really bad name, object is too generic and confusing. you know it's a queryset and not a single object

‘support_article_object’ is not a bad name. It tells the us that its referring to an object, then it tells us what the object is. It’s a logical naming schematic.

everything is an object in python, support_article is also an object so it could be named support_article_object too... and you're the one confused by this "logic" as you queried the wrong object

Solution:
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
def help_center_article_index(request, group):
   
   support_article_queryset    = SupportArticles.objects.filter(support_article_group = group)
   if support_article_queryset.exists():
      meta_property_title       = utils.meta_property_title("Support for "+support_article_queryset.first().support_article_group)
   else:
      meta_property_title       = "No articles available for this group"
   meta_property_description    = utils.meta_property_description("Explore our comprehensive collection of support articles tailored for software developers in the hedge fund industry. Discover best practices, technical insights, and practical guides to enhance your development process and optimize performance. Stay informed and empowered with expert knowledge and resources")
   form                         = create_and_submit_ticket(request)

   context = {
      
      'meta_property_title'         : meta_property_title,
      'meta_property_description'   : meta_property_description,
      'form'                        : form,
      'support_article_queryset'    : support_article_queryset,
      'group'                       : group,

  }
   
   return render (request, 'help_center_article_index.html', context)

The template is as follows:
#help_center_article_index.html
{% for support_article_object in support_article_queryset %}
        <a href="{{group}}/{{support_article_object.support_article_reference}}" class="support-article-index__inserted">
            <h3>{{ support_article_object.support_article_title | title}}</h3>
            <p>{{ support_article_object.support_article_body }}</p>
            <div class="support-article-index__tags-container">
                {% for article_tags in support_article_object.get_support_article_tags %}
                    <div class="support-article-index__tags">{{article_tags | title}}</div>
                {% endfor%}
            </div>
        </a>
        {% empty %}
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">{{meta_property_title}}</h3>
        {% endfor %}

